# Finding text in a PDF document with the same font properties in PDFBox

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I am new to Java and PDFBox. I am trying to find words in a PDF document, store its font properties (font family, XScale, font size etc.) in variables and then find other words with the same font properties using the previously stored values. What should I do with `processTextPosition()` to show font properties of String "References"?

Here is my code:

```
package pdfinjava;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class reference extends PDFTextStripper {
    static ArrayList<String> boldWordList=new ArrayList<String>();
    String boldWord="";
    String c="";
    public reference() throws IOException {
        super.setSortByPosition(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            File input = new File("C:\\abc.pdf");
            document = PDDocument.load(input);
            //  File output=new File("D:/acadmic/7/research/pdf/2.txt");
            PDFTextStripper s=new PDFTextStripper();
            String content = s.getText(document);
            int n= content.indexOf("References");
            String c = content.substring(n, n+10);
            System.out.println(c);

            reference printer = new reference();
            List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
                PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
                //System.out.println("Processing page: " + i);

                PDStream contents = page.getContents();
                if (contents != null) {
                    printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param text The text to be processed
     */
    @Override 

    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {    
        if(text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().isForceBold()){
            boldWord+=text;
            //System.out.println(text);

            System.out.println("String["+ text.getXDirAdj() + ","
            + text.getYDirAdj() + " Font Size=" + text.getFontSize()
            + " Font Family=" + text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontName()
            + " xscale=" + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() 
            + " space=" + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width="+ text.getWidthDirAdj() 
            + "]" + text.getCharacter());
        }
    }
}
```